# \usepackage{listings} prevents file from compiling

Tags: listings, miktex, texstudio, minted, matlab-prettifier

I am trying to use the listings package to show code in my document, but for some reason, if I include this package, the whole document doesn't compile.  I don't get any error messages, just:

> Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex
>
> Process exited normally
> But the document would not update.

My code is simple:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

If I remove \usepackage{listings} as well as the \begin{lstlisting} block, I am able to compile the document normally.

I am using TeXstudio 4.3.1 with MiKTeX (all packages updated).

The same problem happens with other packages that depend on listings (such as mcode and matlab-prettifier mentioned in this post):
[What can I use to typeset MATLAB code in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document)

When I try to use the minted package (code below):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
    test
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error messages:

> Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \begin
>
> Emergency stop. \begin{document}
>
> shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

I have no issues using verbatim, however, but it does not give me the line wrapping feature I need.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `minted` package documentation, [minted](https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) says that `-shell-escape` needs to be added because the `minted` package calls external sources to process the code in Latex. If this is not something that would be preferred then using `verbatim` would be the option with the least configuration changes required.

Comment: The furst MWE runs fine on my system.  Place the curso; over the TeXstudio icon and see if you have two runs going at the same time.

Comment: don't run with nonstopmode. At best run once on a command line simply with `pdflatex yourfile` so that you get a proper error message.